# Addresses of Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

If I have an array declared like this:

```
int a[3][2];
```

stored at address `A`.

Then a+1 is equal to `A+2*4`, this is clear to me, 
but why is `&a+1` equal to `A+6*4`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` is an array of `int[2]`. Which has size `2 * sizeof(int)`. That's why `a + 1 = A + 2*4`. (since `sizeof(int) = 4` in your case)

However, `&a` is a pointer to `int[3][2]`. Since `sizeof(int[3][2]) = 6 * sizeof(int)`, therefore: `&a + 1 = A + 6*4`

Answer (score 2):

> Then a+1 is equal to A+2*4

This is because `a` decays to `int (*)[2]`, and `+1` results in `2 * sizeof(int)`.

> but why is &a+1 equal to A+6*4?

In this case, `&a` returns `int (*)[3][2]`, and `+1` results in `2 * 3 * sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

Because operator & take precedence over operator +.